How can l add H2 tag to tags: in WordPress single page after content?
I am using Tagdiv's Newspaper theme on my website. I am listing all post tags after post like:
Tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 as you can see in the image I added.
I want to give h2 meta tag for ever listing tags in this area.
I modified the loop.single.php file in WordPress theme like this
                        <ul class="td-tags td-post-small-box clearfix">
                            <li><span><?php esc_html_e('TAGS', 'newspaper') ?></span></li>
                            <?php
                                foreach ($td_post_tags as $td_post_tag) { ?>
                                    <li><h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_tag_link($td_post_tag->term_id)) ?>"><?php echo esc_html($td_post_tag->name) ?></a></h2></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>

But nothing has changed and tags still doesn't have h2.
How can I do that?
I want to add h2 tag to every tags listed after post.


I edited the same file loop-single.php like this
// tags
                $td_post_tags = get_the_tags();
                if( !empty($td_post_tags) ) { ?>
                    <div class="td-post-source-tags">
                        <ul class="td-tags td-post-small-box clearfix">
                            <li><span><?php esc_html_e('TAGS', 'newspaper') ?></span></li>
                            <?php
                                foreach ($td_post_tags as $td_post_tag) { ?>
                                    <li><h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_tag_link($td_post_tag->term_id)) ?>"><?php echo esc_html($td_post_tag->name) ?></a></h2></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            <?php }

and it's adding  tag to every tags in list.
Result:
<ul class="td-tags td-post-small-box clearfix">
     <li><span>TAGS</span></li>
     <li><h2><a href="http://demoshop.test/tag/tag2/">tag2</a></h2></li>
     <li><h2><a href="http://demoshop.test/tag/tag3/">tag3</a></h2></li>
</ul>

Overriding file in child theme also worked!

Your code is the same code l shared and it doesnt work. Can you show me your page that this code worked for you? it didnt work for me check pls https://cryptonewsmag.com/apple-design-awards-german-developer-wins-prize-for-the-third-time

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@user1939999  I tried it without installing demo site. After installing demo and required plugin I can see there are options in edit post to select templates, where default template is loading from theme templates but the other templates load tags stucture form file '\plugins\td-cloud-library\shortcodes\single\tdb_single_tags.php'.  I have checked both. Are you using Td cloud  library plugin? and please check which template you have selected for post?

I dont use extra themes or cloud librarry elements. Just running default themes.
